# Return cell of corresponding cells in another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have the following raw data in 2 sheets; Sheet 1 has first names only. Sheet 2 contains first and last name initial.

```
Sheet1 - Raw Data:
COL1    COL2
Sam     ID123
John    ID456
Kim     ID567

Sheet2 - Raw Data:
COL1    COL2    COL3
Jess B  ID555   Return1
Frank A ID111   Return2
John L  ID456   Return3
Sam F   ID123   Return4
Dave A  ID888   Return5
Kim J   ID567   Return6
```

How can I return the following data? Grabbing the corresponding ReturnX, and First name + last name initial only when Sheet1:COL2 matches and is present in Sheet2:COL2

```
Sheet 3 - What I want to return:
COL1    COL2
Sam F   Return4
John L  Return3
Kim J   Return6
```

Comment: `VLOOKUP`? That's pretty basic...

Comment: The problem I'm having with VLOOKUP is, what do I set the lookup_value to? I can't set it to Sheet1:COL1 or Sheet2:COL1 as that's not what I want returned. I am struggling with the logic of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your columns on sheet 2 to a named range. For my example: Name, ID, and Return. Then enter the following formula in Sheet 3 cell A1 and drag it down the column as far as you need:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Name,MATCH(Sheet1!B1,ID,0)),"")`

... and enter this formula in cell B1 and drag it down:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Return,MATCH(Sheet1!B1,ID,0)),"")`

Answer (score 0):

table2Range : reference to cells underneath COL1 in sheet 2

table1Range : reference to cells underneath COL1 in sheet 2

header2Range : reference to cell with COL1 in sheet 2

inputRange  : reference to cell containing input

We'll get it with an

```
IF( NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(inputRange,table1Range,0)),
IFERROR(OFFFSET(header2Range,MATCH(inputRange,table2Range,0),2),"")
,"")
```